# Database management for product release

Tags: sql, database

In our company we are developing a product.
We are relying on the tfs to manage the release issues by using branching and merging.
We still have a problem with the SQL database on how to track changes and send them to the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice software that is very helpful in database management, which is **RedGate  SQL Toolbelt v2010.08.01**

Answer (score 2):

We use [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/):

> Liquibase is an open source (Apache
>   2.0 Licensed), database-independent library for tracking, managing and
>   applying database changes.